# Visual Studio 2022 Theme Not Colorizing Tabs

Tags: themes, visual-studio-2022

I have a VS 2022 Theme that doesn't address the Tabs toolbar colors.  I have a VSTheme Project for it, so can fix it, but I don't know where the colors are in the "All Elements" tab.

Does anyone know how to colorize these elements in the VSTheme Project Editor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems the majority of the color settings are called "FileTab" (example, to change the background color, look for `FileTabActiveGroupBackground`).

Here is a broken down screenshot of some of the color controls:

[image: tabs colors]